# How to serialize a collection property in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping

Disclaimer: I am completely new to Java development. I've done a lot of C# and some NHibernate but this world of @Attributes and get/set methods is completely foreign to me.

Question: I have a very simple persistent object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADMIN_SETTINGS")
public class AdminSettings extends ClientEntity {
    @Column(name = "SAMPLE_ID_PREFIX")
    private String sampleIdPrefix;
    @Column(name = "USE_24_Hr_CLOCK")
    private Boolean use24hrClock;

    private Integer[] FieldsForSampleBoxView;
 ...
```

Mapping that last field I get stuck with. It is a simple list of at most 3 integers. I don't need a one-to-many table, I don't need to aggregate across it, I just need to serialize the collection to a field in the db. Ideally via something human readable but honestly, I don't care.

How do I go about mapping this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it contains at most 3 integers, why not store these three integers in three columns? This would at least be normalized and queryable. If not, then just use a persistent String attribute, and parse this string in the getter and transform to string in the setter:

```
@Column(FIELDS_FOR_SAMPLE_VIEW_BOX)
private String fieldsForSampleViewBox;

public void setFieldsForSampleViewBox(Integer[] array) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] != null) {
            b.append(array[i]);
        }
        if (i < array.length - 1) {
            b.append(',');
        }
    }
    fieldsForSampleViewBox = b.toString();
}

public Integer getFieldsForSampleViewBox() {
    if (fieldsForSampleViewBox == null || fieldsForSampleViewBox.length() == 0) {
        return new Integer[0];
    }
    String[] strings = fieldsForSampleViewBox.split(",");
    Integer[] result = new Integer(strings.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length(); i++) {
        if (!strings[i].equals("") {
            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(strings[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You may also use the @Lob annotation or the @Type(type="serializable") annotation on your Integer array, but then native Java serialization will be used, and it's more fragile and not readable.

Comment: So if I just put on it `@Column("FIELDS_FOR_SAMPLE_VIEW_BOX")` and `@Type(type="serializable")` on my Integer[] array it should work? It honestly wouldn't matter too much if this piece of data got corrupted and the user had to re-select. Can you please include what the @Lob/@Type solution would look like? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it should work. The column should be a binary column. Note that if the data is corrupted, the user won't be able to do anything: an exception will be thrown each time the entity is loaded.

Comment: Ah...ok, THAT would be a problem sure

Comment: The safest solution is to have three columns, or to implement a safe parsing method (which would, for example, return an empty array if any exception is thrown while parsing. I would choose the three-columns solution.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to the first link google returned for "hibernate persist array": you may need [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-custom). Essentially, it says you'll need to plug your own serializer for this into Hibernate. Since I'm not a Hibernate expert, I don't know how express this in annotations.

Much simpler, but not so elegant: don't serialize `int[]` at all, instead hold it's data in serialized form inside `AdminSettings`, say, in a String with custom delimiters (ugh). Or have both `int[]` and serialized form, but it will cost more memory and more CPU to support consistency between them.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I'm asking. I've done this before in NHibernate, but no idea how to express it here. Plus, I would hope (oh god please let it be so) that there is some standard serializer that can handle integer arrays.